# NullPointerException on iterating over a file on atom

Tags: clojure, nullpointerexception, atomic

I'm new to Clojure, and I'm building a small function that reads tuples from a file and check if the first element is already in a `(atom{})`.

But I keep receiving `NullPointerException` at line `((println "OK")))` after the first iteration. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
(defn graph-from-file
  "Expects a string with the path for a file with a list of edges, one in each line,
And builds a graph data structure from these"
  [filepath]
  (def gr (atom{}))
  (with-open [rdr (reader filepath)]
    (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
      (let [[src dst] (str/split line #" ")
            ks (keyword src)]           ;define ks as the keyword
        (println (str "src: " src " dst: " dst " kw: " ks))
        (if (contains? @gr ks)
          ((println "WHAT?"))
          ((println "OK")))
        )))
  )
```

Note that the code is simple, and the outputs (WHAT? and "OK") are here just for demonstration purposes.

Here is the output I get:

```
src: 64 dst: 48 kw: :64
OK
NullPointerException   ****/graph-from-file (core.clj:19)
```

Comment: An additional comment on your code: don't `def`inside a function, it creates a global var. Typically you would want a local variable, so use `let` instead. If you really want a global var, pull the `def` out of the function.

Comment: @schaueho What if I want to return this var? A let is still the right choice?

Comment: Yes, but you don't return the var, but the value of the var, i.e. the atom. cf. http://http://clojure.org/vars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra layer of parentheses:  `((println "OK"))`.

The result of `(println "OK")` is a `nil`, so the extra pair of parenthesis looks like a function call on nil:  `(nil)`.  In Java the equivlant code would be `null()`, which doesn't make any sense.

Remember that in Clojure, parentheses mean "function call".

---

UPDATE 2015-9-17:

If function syntax is:

```
(if <cond-expr>
  <true-expr>
  <false-expr> )
```

The 3 expressions may be either constant values like `5` or a function call like `(+ 2 3)`.  The return value of the entire `(if ...)` expression is the result of either `<true-expr>` or `<false-expr>`.  So we get:

```
(if true
  :wahoo
  "no such luck" ))
;=> :wahoo
```

and

```
(if (< (+ 2 3) 9)
  (str "Two plus three is " (+ 2 3))
  :not-likely ))
;=> Two plus three is 5
```

---

***UPDATE 2015-11-1***

The syntax is as follows:

```
(if test-value
  result-value-if-true
  result-value-if-false)
```

The first example results in `:wahoo` with all three values being literals (i.e. constants).  In Clojure, any value can be replaced by an expression:

```
(if (< 2 3)
  (+ 9 10)
  (- 9 10))
;=> 19
```

Each value in the above example has been replaced by a function call.  The result of `(< 2 3)` is true, so the function `(+ 9 10)` is evaluated and the result of that function is returned as the result of the whole `(if ...)` expression.  So, we get the result `19` instead of `-1`.

Remember, in Clojure parentheses mean "function call".  You have to un-learn the idea from Java, et al that parentheses are often used as a "grouping operator".  In Java,

```
2 = (2) = ((2)) = ...
```

since repeatedly "grouping" a value makes no difference. In Clojure, the syntax `(2)` means "find the function named `2` and call it with zero arguments (in Java this would be `2()` which is illegal).

Comment: Thanks for that! It works. So, just to make sure I got it right, the actual if syntax is

    `(if (function) 
        true body
        false body
    )`

Right?

Answer (score 2):

Don't wrap the `println` calls in two sets of parentheses.  Use only one pair.  What's in parentheses is usually read as a function or macro call.  Clojure evaluates the `println` in the inner parens.  Then `println` returns `nil`, and Clojure tries to use that as a function because of the outer parens.  `nil` is Java's `null`, which causes the exception.

Comment: Alan T. said it first, while I was writing.